# How do I add age of an employee with year and months using ORD report - SAP successfactors

Tags: sap-successfactors

I'm using SAP SuccessFactors and I want to make an ORD report that will give me the age of an employee with his age in years and months. For example today's date is 01/01/2023 and I have an employee that was born in 01/02/2000 his age will be 22.11